# Google Maps v2 showing blank tiles in Tabs

Tags: android

I am implementing google maps v2 api and it is working perfectly fine as a stand alone activity. However as soon as i use the same activity in a tab the map only shows zoom icons but it does not load and is blank.

I am using the following code to display the map in a FragmentActivity in the onCreate:

```
SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment =(SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapview);
mGoogleMap = supportMapFragment.getMap();
```

My TabHost is a Simple activity and I use the following code to setup my mapFragmentActivity:

```
tabview = createTabView(tabhost.getContext(), MAP_TAB);
        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, MapsActivity.class);
        spec = tabhost.newTabSpec(MAP_TAB);
        spec.setIndicator(tabview);
        spec.setContent(intent);
        tabhost.addTab(spec);
```

If i use only the MapActivity it shows the map perfectly. But in tabs its showing blank tiles.
Please guide me what i can do to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

There is a better way to use Tabs  since 3.0 and it is... Tabs in ActionBAr look [HERE](http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/tabs.html). I don't know wich API you are targetting but if it's Under 11 use [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com) instead of native Actionbar to get a backwards compatibility to Android 2.1.